# Understanding undefined key in object when using map

Tags: typescript

This is the MWE:

```
interface Animals {cat:string, dog:string}

let a: Animals|undefined;


if(a){// if we got `a` from somewhere
 [1,2,3].map(v=>a.cat)
 // ----------> ~ Object is possibly 'undefined'
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=22&ssc=1&pln=15&pc=1#code/PTAEHUFMBsGMHsC2lQBd5oBYoCoE8AHSAZVgCcBLA1UABWgEM8BzM%20AVwDsATAGiwoBnUENANQAd0gAjQRVSQAUCEmYKsTKGYUAbpGF4OY0BoadYKdJMoL%20gzAzIoz3UNEiPOofEVKVqAHSKymAAmkYI7NCuqGqcANag8ABmIjQUXrFOKBJMggBcISGgoAC0oACCbvCwDKgU8JkY7p7ehCTkVDQS2E6gnPCxGcwmZqDSTgzxxWWVoASMFmgYkAAeRJTInN3ymj4d-jSCeNsMq-wuoPaOltigAKoASgAywhK7SbGQZIIz5VWCFzSeCrZagNYbChbHaxUDcCjJZLfSDbExIAgUdxkUBIursJzCFJtXydajBBCcQQ0MwAUVWDEQC0gADVHBQGNJ3KAALygABEAAkYNAMOB4GRonzFBTBPB3AERcwABS0%20mM9ysygc9wASmCKhwzQ8ZC8iHFzmB7BoXzcZmY7AYzEg-Fg0HUiQ58D0Ii8fLpDKZgj5SWxfPADlQAHJhAA5SASPlBFQAeS%20ZHegmdWkgR1QjgUrmkeFATjNOmGWH0KAQiGhwkuNok4uiIgMHGxCyYrA4PCCGQUZGSDCWFU4UIY0GEAG9aqh8lTKJxmPxuPBmPPUIvmABfYLuan5SpjxATwQAHy43EgyQykG4AG5ggiVTqp4pQABtACMvAATLwAGYAF0AhPAglR0bkAD4GACWc9V3YIgA)

I am not sure what exactly the error is, it seems to be related to map outputting something or undefined, but why `a` isn't defined?

Comment: You didn't describe the actual error reported by TS; it's that `a` might be `undefined`, not `a.cat`.  I'm going to [edit] so that this is actually a [mre]

Comment: Also slightly perplexed by this as `a` should be inferred as being `Animals` within the scope of the if statement. Assigning `a.cat` to a variable and using that variable in the map is accepted by the compiler (https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIImAWzgGwM7IDeCcYAXHmFKAOYA0yAJgPY0VW0C+AUNzAK4gEYYMxDI8zTBABiIABQBKIt2RrkOCGGRwyaDNnzIAPskGMIMUBEYBuXuuTAY8uIsKrH6gNoBGOgBMdADMALoAdNgADvIAbgC8AHxw4SRgivaeXsgIYpQSUhAAanBQyPE6qaT22Wp+gSER0XFJktIlUBlZyDw8QA). It is beyond my understanding why this is but thought I would share for future commenters

Answer (score 2):

This is a general limitation of TypeScript, described in [microsoft/TypeScript#9998](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998).  The effects of [control flow analaysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis), such as the narrowing of `a` from `Animals | undefined` to `Animals` following the [truthiness check](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#truthiness-narrowing) `if (a)`, do not persist to closed-over values across function boundaries.

Inside the body of the callback `v => a.cat`, therefore, there has been no control flow narrowing of `a`; it is considered to be of type `Animals | undefined`, and therefore you get an error when indexing into it.

The reason this happens is because there is currently no way for the compiler to know that the callback `v => a.cat` is run immediately.  That's out-of-band information *we* have about `Array.prototype.map()`, but from the type system's perspective there's no meaningful difference between `[1,2,3].map` and the following definition of `foo`:

```
function foo(cb: (x: number) => string) {
    setTimeout(() => cb(100), 1000);
}

a = { cat: "abc", dog: "def" };
if (a) {
    foo(v => a.cat) // error!
    // ----> ~ Object is possibly 'undefined'
}
a = undefined;
// later: Uncaught TypeError: a is undefined
```

The `foo()` function takes a callback, and calls it *later*.  And in fact, when it calls it, `a` *is* `undefined`.  So the compiler is, in general, right to complain.  You could hope that the compiler might notice whether or not `a` is ever reassigned and suppress the error if it isn't, but that's a lot of extra work for the compiler to do, and the point of microsoft/TypeScript#9998 is that they haven't found anything yet that would pay for itself in terms of compiler performance.

There's a feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#11498](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11498) to allow the type system to be told that `map()` runs its callback immediately, so that any control flow analysis results can be persisted inside the callback, which would allow `map()` and `foo()` to be treated differently... but for now it's not part of the language.

---

So that's the problem.  The compiler doesn't know that the callback will be run immediately, and it does not scour the source code to check if `a` is ever reassigned to `undefined`, so it errs on the safe side.

Currently the best workaround would be to assign your narrowed value to a new `const` variable, whose type is by definition already narrowed:

```
if (a) {
    const _a = a;
    [1, 2, 3].map(v => _a.cat) // okay
}
```

The `_a` variable, where it exists, is always of type `Animals`, not `Animals | undefined`, so the callback type checks successfully.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHUFMBsGMHsC2lQBd5oBYoCoE8AHSAZVgCcBLA1UABWgEM8BzM+AVwDsATAGiwoBnUENANQAd0gAjQRVSQAUCEmYKsTKGYUAbpGF4OY0BoadYKdJMoL+gzAzIoz3UNEiPOofEVKVqAHSKymAAmkYI7NCuqGqcANag8ABmIjQUXrFOKBJMggBcISGgoAC0oACCbvCwDKgU8JkY7p7ehCTkVDQS2E6gnPCxGcwmZqDSTgzxxWWVoASMFmgYkAAeRJTInN3ymj4d-jSCeNsMq-wuoPaOltigAKoASgAywhK7SbGQZIIz5VWCFzSeCrZagNYbChbHaxUDcCjJZLfSDbExIAgUdxkUBIursJzCFJtXydajBBCcQQ0MwAUVWDEQC0gADVHBQGNJ3KAALygABEAAkYNAMOB4GRonzFBTBPB3AERcwABS0+mM9ysygc9wASmCKhwzQ8ZC8iHFzmB7BoXzcZmY7AYzEg-Fg0HUiQ58D0Ii8fLpDKZgj5SWxfPADlQAHJhAA5SASPlBFQAeS+ZHegmdWkgR1QjgUrmkeFATjNOmGWH0KAQiGhwkuNok4uiIgMHGxCyYrA4PCCGQUZGSDCWFU4UIY0GEAG9Rqh8ldUJROMx+Nx4Mx51SlyMAL7BdzU+ej8eT0AAH1AXG4kGSGUg3AA3MEEaAVTrQFPFCUSjKaAB9cReQYJ9v1AABtABGfgACZ+AAZgAXQCRAGAIJUdB5AA+UAAICWpUHfFR4HiJhFD3RRki4WB6kaHF4HgJVYGkeclVWedOHYRBpG+d9uWwrdhnfT9QMzVAcChSAOFQJUlV47CmKVCCAAYlJ1fhlJUnUnz3QCP1nec+Q5WA+VXdcDOvZJgx3J8XzfD8v2-ZJ6PQrCxDwuo9R0nlLx4G870fYpGAHed7nMBh2GYTAaH2GkyDYMh53EUQrz8zh70UIA)

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of how TypeScript handles uncertainty of variable reassignment. [Here is the discussion on design choice](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998). If you swap your declaration for a `const` the error will be cleared in the flow section and mark it at the initialization.